# How can I get the TTS from azure speech sdk and play it in a HTML audio tag

Tags: reactjs, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk in react for text-to-speech. I want to be able to play the audio generated using an audio element on the webpage. Ideally I would like to obtain the binary data and set it as the source of the element and play the element using js.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be the source of an element? If you can just store the ArrayBuffer of the results data, you can use BaseAudioPlayer to replay that Buffer. For example:

```
var audioBuffer = null;
[...]
synthesizer.synthesisCompleted = function (s, e) {
    audioBuffer = e.result.audioData;
};
[...]
playbackButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var p = new SpeechSDK.BaseAudioPlayer();
    if(!!p && !!audioBuffer) {
      console.log(`playing buffer with length ${audioBuffer.byteLength}`);
      p.playAudioSample(audioBuffer);
    }
});
```

I've tested this on iOS 14.6, but only for Riff WAV. Not sure if it works for other formats.